# I have built my 3rd homemade slot car track from MDF. Stuck on surface paint

Tags: wood, rubber

I have finished my 3rd homemade slot car track from MDF. I have sealed it properly all the way.

My first 2 tracks used a cheap latex paint for the track surface. This was when there was a higher rubber content in the cheap latex .
The higher the rubber content, the better traction the slot cars get with the urethane tires.

Now after 15 yrs has passed the cheap latex no longer seems to have rubber in it. So I am at a loss as to what to look for in order to get the higher latex content.

Comment: You are welcome, but my name is not Bob. How about Flex Seal ? If it is good enough for late night TV viewers it has to be good, NO ?

Comment: It smells like puke/ass but redgard would be a player here.

Comment: Perhaps rubber paint would be better than latex paint.

Answer (score 1):

Roman pro rx35 is a product that leaves  a slight tackiness on surface when dry. It aids adhesion of wallpaper.

[image]

This is more of a comment than answer but I wanted show a picture of the product.

Comment: *a slight tackiness*, +1. IDK what the latex content of any paint is, but I know using a lessor sheen, e.g., flat or eggshell, or adding an aggregate like sand, will improve *traction*.